# How to Set value in Google Spreadsheet using google-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Help me to code a google script to set a value into particular cell of google spreadsheet!

```
 function ...
 {     
    var email_address = ....
 }
 ....
 ....
 var values = copyDoc.getSheetValues(1, 1, 33, 7);
 Logger.log('values:');
 Logger.log(values);
 Logger.log('values logged');
```

Now after this I wanna set a value into my spreadsheet!
How can I do that?
I tried the following code, but dint work.

```
 for(var i=1;i<34;i++)
 {
   for(var j=1;j<8;j++)
   {
     if (values[i][j]=="varEmail")
     {
       values[i][j]=email_address;
     }
   }
 }
```

I have alloted 'varEmail' as cell value in my spreadsheet for row 10 and column A,B,c (like big horizontal cell). Now I wanna replace it with value in variable email_address.
Please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your example `values` is an array containing data starting at row 1 col 1, so just write it back in place like below :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

You might want to get the sheet differently depending on your use case, using `getSheetByName` or `getSheets()[sheet index]` but that will be your choice

Comment: Can you please tell in detail? I don't understand where you want me to replace my code!

Comment: ...
if (values[i][j]=="varEmail")
{
Logger.log('value found');           SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValue(email_address);
Logger.log('EMAIL value is changed in spreadsheet');
}
...
I made code like this!
Now error I got is: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 68, file "Code"). i.e. error at line  if (values[i][j]=="varEmail")!

Comment: Nope, just use set values AFTER the main loop.If no condition true was found it will have no effect, if any change is made in the array then the SS will be updated.